# What are the rules behind the typical indenting conventions of lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, indentation

Note to mods: Please note that this question is NOT AT ALL a question of taste. I am asking for specific information regarding the indenting conventions I have encountered in Spacemacs' default indentation rules for elisp.

Why is this code indented like this by formatters:

```
(defun lispy--maybe-safe-delete-region (beg end)
  "Delete the region from BEG to END.
If `lispy-safe-delete' is non-nil, exclude unmatched delimiters."
  (if lispy-safe-delete
      (let ((safe-regions (lispy--find-safe-regions beg end)))
        (dolist (safe-region safe-regions)
          (delete-region (car safe-region) (cdr safe-region)))
        (test))
    (delete-region beg end)
    (test)))
```

And not like this:

```
(defun lispy--maybe-safe-delete-region (beg end)
  "Delete the region from BEG to END.
If `lispy-safe-delete' is non-nil, exclude unmatched delimiters."
  (if lispy-safe-delete
      (let ((safe-regions (lispy--find-safe-regions beg end)))
        (dolist (safe-region safe-regions)
          (delete-region (car safe-region) (cdr safe-region)))
        (test))
      (delete-region beg end)
      (test)))
```

As you see, the default format has not indented the children of the `if` sexp at the same level. I don't understand the rules by which it operates, because the children of the `let` sexp ARE indented at the same level.

Comment: Vim is indenting as the second snippet.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Curiouser and curiouser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `IF` operator of Emacs Lisp allows **one** *then* form and **multiple** *else* forms. The *else* forms are indented differently from the *then* form for readability.

```
ELISP> (if (> 10 20)
           (print 'foo)
         (princ 'bar)
         (princ 'baz)
         nil)
barbaz
nil
```

Comment: Will the formatting be the same as with CLs `if` iff there is only one alternative expression?

Comment: @Sylwester: No, it would make little sense to have special rules for different number of else forms. Note btw. that some CLs indent like this. LispWorks for example.

Comment: Indeed, this is in contrast to Scheme where the `if` form only accepts a single expression in the "else" part, and where the convention is hence to indent the "else" and the "then" at the same column.